# How do I get the users picture using the Facebook PHP graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I call `$facebook->api('/me?fields=picture');`

All I get is an array back.  How do I get the actual image data?

Comment: Just so you're aware why the down votes, this could have been answered with a google search in about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried /me/picture?

`http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture` should work. This will return the URL referencing a 50x50px jpg. You can also denote the type like so:

`http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?type=large`

`http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?type=small`

Here is a live demo ([check the source for proof](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4d8da509-71dd-43f3-9e61-49cc0d72ec02/view-source)) -

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: Yes, that works, but that is not what I need.  I need to use the Facebook PHP SDK, and have the SDK return the image content itself, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: This call **will** return the image content.  Could you be more specific on the reasons?